# Why is justify-content: space-evenly not valid in Atom?

Tags: css, flexbox, atom-editor

I am trying to use `justify-content: space-evenly;` in my CSS, but Atom shows `space-evenly` as greyed out like it is invalid. This is the relevant code:

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .plan-panel {
      -ms-justify-content: space-evenly;
      -webkit-justify-content: space-evenly;
      -moz-justify-content: space-evenly;
      justify-content: space-evenly; } }
```

And this is a pic of what I see in Atom

[image]

I found this at MDN web docs:

> The alignment is done after the lengths and auto margins are applied,
> meaning that, if in a Flexbox layout there is at least one flexible
> element, with flex-grow different from 0, it will have no effect as
> there won't be any available space.

But, I am not using the `flex-grow` property.

Does anyone have a suggestion for why Atom wont play nice with this property/ value combination?

Comment: `space-evenly` is only supported from Chrome v.60 and Firefox v.52 ... and you can drop all those prefixed values. If you show a minimal code sample, there is a workaround, using pseudo elements.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for directing me to the correct answer.

Comment: @LGSon So...If a value like `space-evenly` is not universally supported, then Atom will indicate it's not valid by greying it out?

Comment: Not knowing Atom fully, being run on Electron, if the render engine it use support a property or property value, I shouldn't grey it out. Also, those software normally doesn't use the latest engine, and if not, it doesn't _understand_ `space-evenly` yet (i.e. Chrome v. 60 was released 07/17, Firefox v. 52 in 03/17).

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate because it's about Atom's syntax highlighting, which is determined by the `language-css` package: https://github.com/atom/language-css

Comment: @HollandWilson I reopened the question, please provide your comment as an answer

Comment: paging @HollandWilson ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C's CSS validator also consider `justify-content: space-evenly` to be wrong possibly due to a small support from most browsers.
Here's what it would say: "`space-evenly` is not a `justify-content` value".